# SuperAdmin Access to a Subsite fails

Tags: multisite, dashboard

In a multisite installation (not a local system), I have logged into the site as the superadmin. There are several subsites defined. Some are 'subfolder' sites, and others have a different domain name ([www.subsite.com](http://www.subsite.com)) than the main site ([www.example.com](http://www.example.com)). The sites with a different domain name have the full URL of https://www.subsite.com defined in that subsite settings.

I can access all site settings from the Network Admin screen. I can access the dashboards of all 'subfolder' sites (like the 'www.example.com/site1' subsite).

But I cannot access the dashboard of https://www.subsite.com . I get this error message:

> You attempted to access the [Subsite's Name] dashboard, but you do not
> currently have privileges on this site. If you believe you should be
> able to access the [Subsite's Name] dashboard, please contact your
> network administrator.

I have checked the htaccess for the multisite, and it is as required. There is not an error.log file in the base folder, or the wp-admin folder.

Note that the above error message is seen only for subsites with a different domain name than the main multisite.

How do I get to the admin dashboard of that site - I am logged in as the superadmin? Note that this is a 'live' site, so changing themes/disabling plugins cannot be done.

Comment: note that super admin status doesn't give you a role on a site, it just bypasses the capability checks with a yes for everything, try adding your super admin user to that site with the administrator role and see if that helps

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. But the superadmin user shows as a user for that site (in the Edit Site, Users via the Network Admin, Sites screen). That screen shows the superadmin user as an 'administrator' role on that site.  I have verified that I am signed on as the superuser of the main site, then go into Network Admin to list the sites, then use the Dashboard link for that site, which causes the error. Nothing in error.log, as detailed in the original question.

Comment: do you have defines for constants in the wp-config.php related to cookies and current site? I've assumed this is all on one singular WordPress install on the filesystem. If you log out and log in via one of these sites does that change anything?

Comment: Nothing non-standard on the site, except for a redirect for the site root to a manual landing page. But that only affects the main site.
I did add an admin user to that site, and then was able to log in with that user. Even though that site had the superuser listed as a user on the subsite. 
Maybe it is because that subsite has their own domain name? Have to do more testing.